# why does finding percentage of pixels of pink color in an image not but black does in this code?

Tags: python, colors, pixel

I have written a code to detect the black and pink pixel percentage in a given image, which seems to work for black but always gives 0.0% for pink, even if the image contains pink. Could someone tell me how I can fix this? Here is the code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os

for i in os.listdir("C:\\Users\\vikas\\Documents\\PyTest"):
    img = cv.cvtColor(cv.imread(f"C:\\Users\\vikas\\Documents\\PyTest\\{i}"), cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    black = [0,0,0]
    pink = [255, 192, 203]

    diff_black = 20
    diff_pink = 20

    boundaries_black = [([ black[0], black[1], black[2] ],[ black[0]+diff_black, black[1]+diff_black, black[2]+diff_black ])]
    boundaries_pink = [([ pink[0]-diff_pink, pink[1]-diff_pink, pink[2]-diff_pink ],[ pink[0]+diff_pink, pink[1]+diff_pink, pink[2]+diff_pink ])]

    scale = 0.3
    height = int(img.shape[0]*scale)
    width = int(img.shape[1]*scale)
    newSize = (width, height)

    img = cv.resize(img, newSize, None, None, None, cv.INTER_AREA)

    for (lower, upper) in boundaries_black:
        lower = np.array(lower, dtype=np.uint8)
        upper = np.array(upper, dtype=np.uint8)

        mask = cv.inRange(img, lower, upper)

        ratio_black = cv.countNonZero(mask)/(img.size/3)
        colorPercent = (ratio_black*100)/scale

        print(f"black pixel percentage: {np.round(colorPercent, 2)}")

    for (lower, upper) in boundaries_pink:
        lower = np.array(lower, dtype=np.uint8)
        upper = np.array(upper, dtype=np.uint8)

        mask = cv.inRange(img, lower, upper)

        ratio_pink = cv.countNonZero(mask)/(img.size/3)
        colorPercent = (ratio_pink*100)/scale

        print(f"pink pixel percentage: {np.round(colorPercent, 2)}")
```

[The output when I print [255, 192, 203] RGB value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeFHB.png)

Comment: Are you sure you defined 'pink' correctly, that you didn't swap color channels etc... ? [mre]

Comment: @Julien I ran a code to check the output of [255, 192, 203] RGB value, and have added it to the original post. It is indeed pink